# Making javascript synchronous code from nested asychronous calls with a modal library?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asynchronous, synchronous

So, this might be a bit confusing. A while back when Chromium decided to kill their modal support, our place found a library that seemed to work great (and yes, they want it parsed out between webkit/non-webkit [basically we have two versions of this thing running in either Firefox or Chrome])

```
function AddToConfig(){
....
....
....

if(/ipad|android|webkit/i.test(navigator.userAgent)){
    $.showModalDialog({
    url: "get_required.php?maxSelect="+max+"&forceReload="+Math.random(),
    dialogArguments: window,
    height: 270,
    width: 510,
    position: 'top',
    onClose: function(){ numReq = this.returnValue; return retAction(numReq); }
    });
}else{
    numReq = window.showModalDialog ("get_required.php?maxSelect="+max+"&forceReload="+Math.random(),             window, "dialogHeight:250px; dialogWidth:500px; center:yes; help:no; resizable:no; scroll:no; status:no; edge:raised");
    return numReq;
}
```

(Lifted/more info here)
http://extremedev.blogspot.com/2011/03/windowshowmodaldialog-cross-browser-new.html

For a while, it worked fine. All the code replacement thus far has been situations where user clicks button, popup (now modal) happens, it does its thing and returns a value that 99% of the time requires a iFrame or something to be refreshed, so timing wasn't a issue. Great, awesome.

The situation I'm in right now, this modal call is in the middle of a bunch of other calculations. It fires if it reaches down this chain of ifthens. However, the code above seems to be making it a issue. I've tried doing callbacks like below (and maybe I'm just writing them wrong) and that hasn't worked. Hell, the comments in that URL above say doing this is a little tricky. Here's kinda (what I hope) is enough.
So, I want to hit AddToConfig(), ClearSelections(), printText() which seems simple in and of itself, but the GetRequired asynch-y call is throwing everything off.

Main code in question (Original):

```
//What kicks it off
<input type=button class="button3" id=btnAdd onClick='AddToConfig()' value='Add' onMouseDown="this.className='button3down'" onMouseUp="this.className='button3over'" onMouseOver="this.className='button3over'" onMouseOut="this.className='button3'">

  function AddToConfig(){   
    ....
    ...
    if (meowmeowmeowmeow)
    {
       ....
    }
    else
    {
        //Modal - NEEDS TO PAUSE
        var requiredCount = GetRequired(arrConfigSet[--lenS][2]);
        //Modal - NEEDS TO PAUSE

        arrConfigSet[lenS][1] = requiredCount;
        arrConfigSet[lenS][2]++;
    }

    arrConfigItem[lenI] = new Array ();
    ...
    ...
    ClearSelections();
}

 function GetRequired(max)
 {
        //This is modal and dumb and makes me cry

        var numReq = '';

    if(/ipad|android|webkit/i.test(navigator.userAgent)){
        $.showModalDialog({
        url: "get_required.php?maxSelect="+max+"&forceReload="+Math.random(),
        dialogArguments: window,
        height: 270,
        width: 510,
        position: 'top',
        onClose: function(){ numReq = this.returnValue; return numReq; }
    });
}else{
    //This is fine, because it pops up a new window.
    numReq = window.showModalDialog ("get_required.php?maxSelect="+max+"&forceReload="+Math.random(),             window, "dialogHeight:250px; dialogWidth:500px; center:yes; help:no; resizable:no; scroll:no; status:no; edge:raised");
        return numReq;
    }
}

function ClearSelections(){
    //various UI resetting of values
    printText(); 
}
```

Main code in question (My callback version):

```
<input type=button class="button3" id=btnAdd onClick='AddToConfig(function(){ClearSelections();})' value='Add' onMouseDown="this.className='button3down'" onMouseUp="this.className='button3over'" onMouseOver="this.className='button3over'" onMouseOut="this.className='button3'">

if (meowmeowmeowmeow)
{
   ....
}
else
{
var requiredCount = GetRequired(arrConfigSet[--lenS][2]);

//So, here's my problem, that line above works fine with Firefox/non webkit because 
    //Popup windows make things work fine and great. With this modal thing we found
    //on the internet (in getRequired()) this line of code keeps going and runs stuff below
    // the line and keeps going. I need this to 
    //stop here. I've tried to do something like put that requiredCount in a while loop, but
    //then it says Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '2' of undefined on that var requiredCount.
    //For the record, this is all done from a onClick event on a button if it makes a difference.
    //
    //
    //alert('test:' + arrConfigSet[--lenS][2]);  //Returns a value!
    //      var requiredCount;
    //      while(typeof variable_here === 'undefined'){
    //          requiredCount = GetRequired(arrConfigSet[--lenS][2]);
    //      }


    //This keeps running when in Webkit, I need that requiredCount to be set and finalized with
    //the modal window gone before this continues.

    arrConfigSet[lenS][1] = requiredCount;
    arrConfigSet[lenS][2]++;
}

arrConfigItem[lenI] = new Array ();
...
...
callback();
}

 function GetRequired(max)
 {
        //This is modal and dumb and makes me cry

        var numReq = '';

    if(/ipad|android|webkit/i.test(navigator.userAgent)){
        $.showModalDialog({
        url: "get_required.php?maxSelect="+max+"&forceReload="+Math.random(),
        dialogArguments: window,
        height: 270,
        width: 510,
        position: 'top',
        onClose: function(){ numReq = this.returnValue; return numReq; }
    });
}else{
    //This is fine, because it pops up a new window.
    numReq = window.showModalDialog ("get_required.php?maxSelect="+max+"&forceReload="+Math.random(),             window, "dialogHeight:250px; dialogWidth:500px; center:yes; help:no; resizable:no; scroll:no; status:no; edge:raised");
        return numReq;
    }
}

function ClearSelections(){
    //various UI resetting of values
    printText(); 
}
```

Does anyone have any ideas on how I can get the JS to stop in its tracks until the script gets that return value? It gets it fine, but by the time it does, the rest of the code after it ran.

Note, we're running jQuery 1.4, so promise() is out of the question and I'm not in any position to push for anything newer. The code is kinda a rat's nest as it.

Comment: You can't pause Javascript execution to wait for an async result.  It simply can't be done.  Instead you have to restructure your code to put the code that needs to wait for the result inside the completion callback (or called from the callback).

Comment: basically: just break your code into two halves, wrap into functions, before() and after(), making any shared variables global/psudeo global, then call after() from the callback of before() (chrome) or from the bottom of before() (everyone else)

Answer (score 0):

You can implement your own simple deferred library, or simply pass in a function that get's called when everything is complete. Simple example:

```
var whenDone = function(res) { alert('I\'m Done: ' + res); };

doComplexTask(whenDone);
```

And the doComplexTask:

```
function doComplexTask(completeFn) {
    //Do some crazy work here that takes a long time (Or is asynchronous)
    var res = crazyWork();
    completeFn(res);
}
```

A simple jfiddle can be found [here](http://jsfiddle.net/u9xcz2ah/).